# DetachedCriteria in NHibernate with OR with external variable

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to implement SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @subtype varchar()
SET subtype=null

SELECT E.* FROM ErrorCRM 
WHERE TypeError='A'
AND (SubtypeError=B or @subtype is null)
```

My DetachedCriteria is this:

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For<ErrorCRM>("e")
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("TipoError", TipoError))
.Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
.Add(Expression.Eq(SubTipoError,null))
.Add(Expression.Eq("SubTipoError", SubTipoError))
)
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Sentido", Sentido))
.Add(Restrictions.Where<ErrorBase>(e => e.Hs >= HsDesde && e.Hs < HsHasta))
.AddOrder(Order.Desc("Hs"));

var errores = query.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<ErrorCRM>();
```

But for some reason I get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." What's happening and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve if I need to build a different detached criteria for each one. I add it in case someone can be useful. The alternative is to build the query line by line

```
             DetachedCriteria query = null;

            query = DetachedCriteria.For<ErrorCRM>("e");
            query= query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("TipoError", TipoError));
            if (SubTipoError != null) {
                query = query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("SubTipoError", SubTipoError));
                }
            query = query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Sentido", Sentido));
            query = query.Add(Restrictions.Where<ErrorBase>(e => e.Hs >= HsDesde && e.Hs < HsHasta));
            query = query.AddOrder(Order.Desc("Hs"));


            var errores = query.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<ErrorCRM>();
```